# User list array filtering by containing the tag by RegExp in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

User list array filtering by containing the tag. I have an array of user list and I want to filter by tag contain using array `filter` `match` and RegExp for matching contain text its work but not get expected result.

```
    let users=[{id:1,name:'john',tags:'a,b,c,v'},{id:2,name:'die',tags:'a,b,w,x'},{id:3,name:'ren',tags:'c,p,q,n'}];
    let tagString='a,b,c';
    let tagStringQuery = new RegExp(tagString, "i");

    let data=users.filter((user) => user.tags.match(tagStringQuery)).map((user)=> user);
    console.log('data',data);

    O/P = [{id:1,name:'john',tags:'a,b,c,v'}]

    but expected result is all user list which contains an 'a' or 'b' or 'c' tag.
```

Comment: `let tagString='(a|b|c)';` this would probably give you required results , hope this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really not a job for a regexp. Ideally you would have tags as `Set` instances, using intersection with a query `Set` to check for presence of tags.

If you insist on regexp though, you can't directly search for `a,b,c` to find if any of `a`, `b` or `c` is present: you would need to search for `a|b|c` (i.e. `tagString.split(',').join('|')`). If tags are of more than one letter, then you need to worry about substrings, so the search string should be `\b(a|b|c)\b`, and you should [regexp-escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3561493/is-there-a-regexp-escape-function-in-javascript) all the strings. And if you have multi-word tags or weird characters in them, you would need to search for `,(a|b|c),` inside `"," + user.tags + ","`.

Answer (score 0):

`tagstring` has to be `'a|b|c'` instead of `'a,b,c'` in case you want to apply `or` operator to those tags

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work fine without regex

```
let data = users.filter(x=>
  tagString
  .split(",")
  .some(r=>
    x.tags.split(",").includes(r)));
```